# Ideal whose power is free.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Suppose that $A$ is a local ring and $I \subset A$ an ideal such that $I^d$ is a free $A$-module i.e. $I^d = (f)$ for some non zero divisor $f \in A$ (meaning $A \xrightarrow{\times f} A$ is injective).

It is possible for $I$ to not be principal?

I am pretty sure this cannot happen if $I$ is prime and $A$ is a UFD. But I am interested in a more general setting.

If $f$ is allowed to be a zero divisor then it is possible for $I^d$ to be principal but $I$ not be. For example, we can take $f = 0$ and the maximal ideal of an Artinian ring.

I am mostly interested in the Noetherian case but am curious if the answer is different for non noetherian $A$.

Comment: How could $(f)$ be free if $f$ is a zero-divisor (excepting the trivial case you mentioned $f=0$)?

Comment: My point was i know examples when we weaken "free" to "principal".

Comment: The starting point when looking for an example should be a local ring with non-principal maximal ideal. Maybe localize a number ring at a singular prime?

Comment: If the projective dimension of $I$ is finite, then the answer is no.